# Definite integral of the exponential of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration

I am doing a modelling project where I have derived that the value of the probability of an event is proportional to the following integral--

$$\int_{-p}^q e^{-\frac{0.5}{\sigma ^2}(ax^2 + bx + c)}dx$$

Here, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers, while $p$, $q$ and $\sigma$ are non-negative real numbers.

I am not adept at such integration, I will be grateful if someone can help me in solving it, either by directly showing how it is done, providing me suggestions or even resources to read so that I can solve it.

Comment: I don´t think it can be solved algebraically. You probably have to use the values of the normal distribution.

Comment: You can write it in terms of $\mathrm{erf}$ functions. Is that OK?

Comment: And now? Any further questions?

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$ax^2+bx+c=\left(\sqrt ax+\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

then

$$\int_{-p}^q e^{-\frac{0.5}{\sigma ^2}(ax^2 + bx + c)}dx=e^{-\frac{0.5}{\sigma ^2}\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)}\int_{-p}^q e^{\frac{0.5\left(\sqrt ax+\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)^2}{\sigma ^2}}dx$$

then proceed by a change of variable using [**normal distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

As @user clearly explained, completing the square and changing variable leads to the gaussion integral.

To make notations simpler
$$\int_{-p}^q e^{-\frac{ax^2 + bx + c}{2\sigma ^2}}dx=K\left(\text{erf}(P)+\text{erf}(Q) \right)$$ where
$$K=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2a}} \sigma\, \exp\left({\frac{b^2-4 a c}{8 a \sigma ^2}}\right)\qquad P=\frac{2 a p-b}{2 \sqrt{2a}  \sigma }\qquad Q=\frac{2 a q+b}{2 \sqrt{2a}  \sigma }$$

Now, the problem is the computation of $\text{erf}(t)$ which is available is most environments. If you do not acess it, there are quite good approximations. Below is one I made  a few years ago
$$\text{erf}(t)\approx \sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac 4 {\pi}\,\frac{1+\alpha\, t^2}{1+\beta \,t^2}\,t^2 \Big)}$$ where
$$\alpha=\frac{10-\pi ^2}{5 (\pi -3) \pi } \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=\frac{120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2}{15 (\pi -3) \pi }$$ which gives a maximum absolute error of $0.0002$ around $t=1.69$.